# convert moment's "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a" to isoStringFormat

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date string in the moment format "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a" ("December 22nd 2016, 2:00 pm). How to convert it into ISOString format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using moment you can use.

```
moment().toISOString();
```

This method takes your date and converts it to ISOString format.

Comment: I have date, for example date = "December 22nd 2016, 2:00 pm"; moment(date).toISOString(); is giving me "0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NaNZ".

Comment: I think its not able to convert because of the format

Comment: try moment("December 22nd 2016, 2:00 pm").format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = moment("December 22nd 2016, 2:00 pm","MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");
alert(date.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
$(function() {
var dateString = "December 22nd 2016, 2:00 pm"
var d = moment(dateString,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a").toDate();
  console.log(d.toISOString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/1.7.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```